# Objective-C NSFileManager works fine on simulator but Operation not permitted error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=257 on device when check file size

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, react-native, file

I need to check size with Objective-C of external file which is shared to my react native app.

I got url which works fine without getting file attributes:

```
file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/61894F8B-0001-40C2-856E-F30D4663F7A7/File%20Provider%20Storage/Instrukcja_Welcome_to.pdf
```

and

```
NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [fileManager attributesOfItemAtPath:url.relativePath error:&error];
NSNumber *fileSize = fileAttributes[NSFileSize];
```

works perfectly on simulator but when I use physical device I got error:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=257 "The file
> “Instrukcja_Welcome_to.pdf” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have
> permission to view it."
> UserInfo={NSFilePath=/private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/61894F8B-0001-40C2-856E-F30D4663F7A7/File
> Provider Storage/Instrukcja_Welcome_to.pdf,
> NSUnderlyingError=0x280eeb240 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1
> "Operation not permitted"}}

I tried:

```
  NSFileCoordinator *fileCoordinator = [[NSFileCoordinator alloc] initWithFilePresenter:nil];
  [fileCoordinator coordinateReadingItemAtURL:url options:NSFileCoordinatorReadingWithoutChanges error:&error byAccessor:^(NSURL *newURL) {
      fileAccessGranted = YES;
  }];
```

and added

```
<key>NSFileUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app requires access to files.</string>
```

to info.plist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution turned out to be quite simple:

```
NSURL *url = = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/61894F8B-0001-40C2-856E-F30D4663F7A7/File Provider Storage/Downloads/Instrukcja_Welcome_to.pdf"];
BOOL isAccessGranted = [url startAccessingSecurityScopedResource]; 
if (isAccessGranted) {
    NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [fileManager attributesOfItemAtPath:url.relativePath error:&error];
    NSNumber *fileSize = fileAttributes[NSFileSize];
}
[url stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource];
```

The key thing is to use `startAccessingSecurityScopedResource` method on `NSURL *url` before using file and after finishing to use `stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource`